# Не работает DNS на Win 10

Tags: сеть, windows-10

В общем, обновили рабочий пк до Win 10 и все настройки прописаны в точности, как было на старом пк:

1. Домен такой же как и был ранее
2. IP машины такой же
3. ДНСы прописаны такие же, как и были ранее и они успешно пингуются

Однако при попытке зайти на внутренний ресурс ловлю сообщение в браузере, что не удалось разрешить имя.

При этом адаптер рабочий , так как в интернет меня нормально пускает.

На машине всего 1 адаптер.

Куда копать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прописал еще WINS и все заработало.